# If $a,b,n$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(a+x,b+y) > 1$ for each $x,y\in\{0,1,...,n\}$ then prove that $\min\{a,b\} > n^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for ways to approach the following problem:

If $a,b,n$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(a+x,b+y) > 1$ for each  $x,y\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$ then prove that $\min\{a,b\}\geq n^n$.

But more than that specific thing, I'd like to have a way to accurately enough approximate the smallest the $a$'s and $b$'s have to be in relation to a certain $n$.

Comment: My current idea is to find for each n, how many prime factors do the associated a's and b's need to have. That way I can give a lower bound for min{a,b} based on the primorial. I think that for each n, the associated a's and b's need to have at least n prime factors. Do you think this could be proven?

Comment: My guess is that the numbers may be of the form, $a = n!$ and $b = s(s+1)...(s+n)$ both these have O($n^n$)

Comment: They may be but not necessarily, I think. I have a minimal pair for n=1, which is a=14 and b=20. They don't get smaller than 14 (confirmed via some paper online). For n=2 I have a=104, b=6200. 104 is as small as it gets for n=2 by the way, also confirmed via some online sources. And these numbers do not conform to your suggestion.

Comment: I was making the statement for n at least as large as 10.